# In C# how can I truncate a byte[] array

Tags: c#

I have a byte[] array of one size, and I would like to truncate it into a smaller array?

I just want to chop the end off.

Comment: Its essential to understand that ALL of the answers below ONLY affect the SPECIFIC VARIABLE holding the array. That is, if you have two variables `a` and `b` pointing to your array, and you use Copy or Resize to change `a`, `b` will still be pointing to the ORIGINAL ARRAY! As [jason points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8214111/199364), you need to use a `List` if you want an object whose length can be changed. That is, if you have other variables pointing to the object, and you need ALL such variables to see the change.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Arrays are fixed-size in C# (.NET).

You'll have to copy the contents to a new one.

```
byte[] sourceArray = ...
byte[] truncArray = new byte[10];

Array.Copy(sourceArray , truncArray , truncArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 31):

You could use [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx), but all this really does is make a truncated copy of the original array and then replaces the original array with the new one.

Answer (score 9):

```
    private static void Truncate() {

        byte[] longArray = new byte[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

        Array.Resize(ref longArray, 5);//longArray = {1,2,3,4,5}

        //if you like linq
        byte[] shortArray = longArray.Take(5).ToArray();

    }
```

Comment: Slightly ambiguous as you aren't making it clear that Take(5) takes from the front. An example that didn't use the midpoint might be better

Answer (score 7):

I usually create an extension method:

```
 public static byte[] SubByteArray(this byte[] byteArray, int len)
    {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[len];
        Array.Copy(byteArray, tmp, len);

        return tmp;
    }
```

Which can be called on the byte array easily like this:

```
buffer.SubByteArray(len)
```

Comment: To clarify, in OP's case, usage would be `buffer = buffer.SubByteArray(len);`

Answer (score 4):

You can't truncate an array in C#. They are fixed in length.

If you want a data structure that you can truncate and acts like an array, you should use `List<T>`. You can use the [`List<T>.RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) method to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

By the way, Array.Resize method takes much more time to complete. In my simple case, I just needed to resize array of bytes (~8000 items to ~20 items):

1. Array.Resize // 1728 ticks
2. Array.Copy // 8 ticks

Comment: This is probably not a valid result, given that Resize internally uses copy. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs  I suspect a problem with your test code - would need to see exactly what you did. That huge time difference - is it possible you created a new array each time in the Resize test, but not in the copy test? Or that you didn't run your test loop enough times to average out any interrupts? Or maybe something about Resize allows interruptions more readily than Copy, making it hard to test accurately.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use ellipse notation in C#.

```
var truncArray = sourceArray[..10];
```

Answer (score -1):

Either use Array.Resize as already mentioned or if, like in my case, your target is a property and it won't allow it, use array = array.Take(x).ToArray().  I didn't test the performance of this but I would think it might be faster than creating a new temp array, resizing, and assigning that. The ellipse notation answer wouldn't work for me because it requires C# 8 and we're on 7.1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).