# How to Divide an array on c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multiprocessing

I have to  do a program that  read and image  and puts it into a byte array

`var Imagenoriginal = File.ReadAllBytes("10M.bmp");`

And Divide That byte Array into  3 Diferent Arrays in order to send each one  of this new arrays to other computer ( Using Pipes ) to process them there and finally take them back to the origial computer and finally give the result.
But my question Is  how do I do an Algorithm  able to  divide the byte array  in three different  bytes arrays  if the image selected can have diferent size.
Thanks for your help,  have a nice day. =)

Comment: Are the arrays to be more or less equal in size, or can they be different?

Comment: More or less equals =)

Comment: `buffer.Length / 3` ? With a little care for the leftover bytes. The smart tihing is of course not to use ReadAllBytes() but ReadBytes(offset, length) instead.

Comment: And how to do that Little care =/

Comment: Side note, but are you sure you can divide a bitmap this way? That is a file with structure: there's a header, scanlines and pixels in there. What can the other process do with broken scanlines or pixels and without the header?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I was dividing a bitmap in similiar way in my project. We had a WCF service, which we did not want to get packets of size bigger then 1 000 bytes, and we had to send 2MP pickures in WP8. As long as you join them together in right order after that, it should work.

Comment: When you reassemble it then that's OK but there is at least a suggestion of independent processing here.

Comment: For copying segments (efficiently), look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8214088/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide length of array, so you have three integers `n1`, `n2` and `n3` with all of them summing up to `array.Length`. Then, this snippet, using LINQ should be of help:

```
var arr1 = sourceArray.Take(n1).ToArray();
var arr2 = sourceArray.Skip(n1).Take(n2).ToArray();
var arr3 = sourceArray.Skip(n1+n2).Take(n3).ToArray();
```

Now, in `arr1`,`arr2` and `arr3` you will have three parts of your source array. You need to use LINQ, so in the beginning of the code don't forget `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: And don't forget `.ToArray()`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Oh my. I didn't use arrays in ages, and truthfully said I forgot about LINQ returning IEnumerable or similiar. Fixed that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> DivideArray<T>(this T[] array, int size)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < (float)array.Length / size; i++)
    {
        yield return array.Skip(i * size).Take(size);
    }
}
```

The call like this:

```
var arr = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6};
var dividedArray = arr.DivideArray(3);
```

Here is a LINQ approach:

```
public List<List<byte>> DivideArray(List<byte> arr)
{
    return arr
             .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
             .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 100)
             .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
             .ToList();
}
```

Comment: It'll work but it doesn't look like something you would want to scale up.

Comment: After calling second `DivideArray`, you need to call `ToArray()` on result, as it returns a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `Streams`? You could extend the `Stream` class to provide the desired behavior, as follows:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static IEnumerable<byte[]> ReadBytes(this Stream input, long bufferSize)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int read;

        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                tempStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                yield return tempStream.ToArray();
            }            
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<byte[]> ReadBlocks(this Stream input, int nblocks)
    {
        long bufferSize = (long)Math.Ceiling((double)input.Length / nblocks);
        return input.ReadBytes(bufferSize);
    }
}
```

- The `ReadBytes` extension method reads the `input` Stream and returns its data as a sequence of byte arrays, using the specified `bufferSize`.
- The `ReadBlocks` extension method calls `ReadBytes` with the appropriate buffer size, so that the number of elements in the sequence equals `nblocks`.

You could then use `ReadBlocks` to achieve what you want:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FileStream inputStream = File.Open(@"E:\10M.bmp", FileMode.Open);
        const int nblocks = 3;

        foreach (byte[] block in inputStream.ReadBlocks(nblocks))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes", block.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Note how `ReadBytes` uses `tempStream` and `read` to write in memory the bytes read from the *input stream* before converting them into an array of bytes, it solves the problem with the *leftover bytes* mentioned in the comments.