# Reading files in c# with filestream and streamreader

Tags: c#, byte, filestream, streamreader, readline

I have a file, which contains data, I want to read it as byte[] and divide into 3 blocks. First line might be read as string, then 2nd block, might be 1-3 length of lines and all left bytes as block 3.

I was wondering, how can I get that block 1 and block 2 would be a string made of byte[], block 3 would be kept byte[].

File:

```
00256000 12      // block 1 single line
a2#b2#c2#d2#e2#  //
1#               //  block 2 readline doesn't fit, unknown length of lines
1#               //
—q3л             // block 3 left bytes
```

I was trying to do FileStream.Read(bytes, 0, file.length), but it only reads all bytes.

StreamReader.ReadLine() is suitable only for 1st line, but it reads plain string, not bytes, it skips '\n' , '\r' etc.

I don't know which way is better to read files and it would be perfect to read allbytes and somehow divide them to these 3 blocks, to have exact block size.

Comment: This might help : [How to Divide an array on c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29593048/3052062)

Comment: oh, great stuff, I can simply read all, and check whether is special symbol or not and then get an index of that symbol and divide my blocks as skip(index),take(anotherindex) . thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all bytes and iterate through buffer searching for line endings. When you find line endings convert textparts with

```
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, start_len, end_len);
```

p.s. be sure to use exact encoding... UTF8 is an example...

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the data members you want, mark it as [serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx), then serialize the data (i.e. save it to a file) and deserialize it whenever you want the data.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Data1
{
    public Data1()
    {
    }

    public String[] Block { get; set; }
}
```

To load that data after you have saved it, use some technique like this:

```
public Data1 Load(string filename)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
    {
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var deserializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            return deserializer.Deserialize(stream) as Data1;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I won't do it all for you, though! You need to look into how to Serialize an instance of **Data1**.

Comment: so if I understood it, I dont need filestream or streamreader, I have to use this object serialization to achieve my three blocks? hope it's not very difficult, thanks for an option :)

Comment: Just add all of  your data to the array of strings (I called it `Block` in my example, but you could call it anything). Pull the data out when you are ready for it.

Comment: it's really messy, I believe, that it is possible to workaround my problem that ikxx suggested, it's more simple for newbie as me :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is very convenient method for reading small files, it returns array of lines.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename");
```