# How would you create these arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I have got a "project" where I am only allowed to use arrays. In this project, I have to read data from a txt file then for example find the second-best lap time among runners and etc.

I can always calculate the correct answer, but I am not sure about my array management.

As you know, in C# you have to provide the length of the array at initialization. Since there are tasks where I don't know the size of the array what I did was declare a far bigger array then use this function:

```
private static string[] ArraySimplyfier(string[] strs, int index)
{
    string[] returnStr = new string[index];

    for (int i = 0; i < returnStr.Length; i++)
    {
        returnStr[i] = strs[i];
    }

    return returnStr;
}
```

As you can see it "clears" the nulls from the array, but the thing is I have to create it for every type of array which is not ideal. Do you have any other ideas for my problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can calculate the needed length before initializing the first array. If it's random (like user input), then you should not be using arrays. Show us the initial problem so we might help.

Comment: can you use IEnumerable<> ?

Comment: I think that was the purpose of this project: showing you that arrays are fixed-sized. If you want to grow dynamically, use a `List<T>` instead.

Comment: What does _"I have to create it for every type of array which is not ideal."_ mean? Your code works, and if you have to do an exercise that shows how arrays work, you've done it.

Comment: So here is an example from my project: There are numerous cars in a database and for example, I have to collect all the cars which are red into an array. I won't really know how big is the array until I collected all the elements. 
And yes it works, I was just curious maybe someone knows a better way

Comment: so you either use a dynamically growing collection-type such as a list, or live with it. There´s no other way as long as you use array.

Comment: "but the thing is I have to create it for every type of array which is not ideal" What do you mean by "for every type"? Which types you refer to? What are the possible types for your array?

Comment: Your approach is perfectly fine, as long as you define the behavior when the array buffer is exceeded. Also, you should probably be using `Array.Copy` or `CopyTo` instead of a `for` loop, if it is permitted..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use generics. That way u have one method for every array type.

Your method would look like this:

```cs
private static T[] ArraySimplyfier<T>(T[] array, int index)
        {
            T[] result = new T[index];

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = array[i];
            }

            return result;
        }
```

and u can call this method like this:

```cs
//example for a string array
ArraySimplyfier<string>(new string[45], 17); //replace 'new string[45]' with your array
```

Comment: how would generics solve the problem of an unkown array-size?

Comment: It allows me to call ArraySimplifier for any arrays

Comment: He said "As you can see it "clears" the nulls from the array, but the thing is I have to create it for every type of array which is not ideal. Do you have any other ideas for my problem?" So for me it sounds like his solution works but he would need to write the same method for every possible data type. With generics this is no longer necessary.

Comment: Indeed, you seem to be only one that focuses on that point of the question.

Comment: Yes all the methods provided were good and worked but I will go with @Tomsen 's solution!

Answer (score 3):

Creating new, bigger arrays and copying is the way to go. You are on the right track there. This is basically what List is doing under the hood (in an optimized way).

If you need this for multiple types, you could look into generic methods. Generics allow you to specify classes and methods for multiple types.

Answer (score 1):

A [List](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) will double in size when it gets too small, you can do the same. Check the "Add/EnsureCapacity" implementation for List on github.

```
// Adds the given object to the end of this list. The size of the list is
// increased by one. If required, the capacity of the list is doubled
// before adding the new element.
//
public void Add(T item) {
    if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
    _items[_size++] = item;
    _version++;
}

// Ensures that the capacity of this list is at least the given minimum
// value. If the currect capacity of the list is less than min, the
// capacity is increased to twice the current capacity or to min,
// whichever is larger.
private void EnsureCapacity(int min) {
    if (_items.Length < min) {
        int newCapacity = _items.Length == 0? _defaultCapacity : _items.Length * 2;
        // Allow the list to grow to maximum possible capacity (~2G elements) before encountering overflow.
        // Note that this check works even when _items.Length overflowed thanks to the (uint) cast
        if ((uint)newCapacity > Array.MaxArrayLength) newCapacity = Array.MaxArrayLength;
        if (newCapacity < min) newCapacity = min;
        Capacity = newCapacity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your question seems to be *"when filtering an array, how do I know the number of elements on beforehand, to get the size of the target array?"* - you don't.

Either loop twice over the source array, once to get the count and then do the copy, or start with an equally sized array, keep the count and [truncate the array by copying it to a new one with the size capped to the number of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214072/in-c-sharp-how-can-i-truncate-a-byte-array).